# Wrapping markup sentance with sed

Tags: sed

Text:

`\item Further course of adolescent \uline{maturation and synaptic questions} to identify genes and circuit development factors associated with departures from normal developmental functioning, and \uline{points in prodromal stages where intervention} might particularly be targeted;`

Goal: substitute `\uline{ text... }` to `{\color{cname}\uline{ text... }}` in the paragraph

Code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/zsh
sed -i -n "96,300 {
s/\(\\\\uline{.*}\)/{\\\\color{cname}\1}/g
}" tmpName.tex

# issue: can't parse the second \uline !!
```

However, got the output like this:

`\item Further course of adolescent {\color{cname}\uline{maturation and synaptic questions} to identify genes and circuit development factors associated with departures from normal developmental functioning, and \uline{points in prodromal stages where intervention}} might particularly be targeted;`

Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed  's#\\uline{[^}]*}#{\\color{cname}&}#g' file
```

add the line range or `-i` if you needed.

test with your text:

```
kent$  cat f
\item Further course of adolescent \uline{maturation and synaptic questions} 
\uline{points in prodromal stages where intervention} foo

kent$  sed  's#\\uline{[^}]*}#{\\color{cname}&}#g' f
\item Further course of adolescent {\color{cname}\uline{maturation and synaptic questions}} 
{\color{cname}\uline{points in prodromal stages where intervention}} foo
```

Comment: Though, still have problems with `\uline{\textbf{not} intended for clinical diagnosis at the current time} foo.`

Comment: @user3069585 yes, that line assumes that there is no nested `{}`s.